# error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++

there is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Flacon
{
private:
  string nom;
  double volume;
  double pH;

public:
    Flacon(string nom, double volume, double pH): nom(nom), volume(volume), pH(pH) {}
    ostream& etiquette(ostream&) const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const Flacon &);
    Flacon& operator+(Flacon const&);

};

Flacon& Flacon::operator+(Flacon const& f){
    this->nom=this->nom + f.nom;
    this->volume+= f.volume;
    this->pH=-log((this->volume * pow(10,-this->pH) + f.volume * pow(10,-f.pH))/(this->volume + f.volume));
    return *this;

ostream& Flacon::etiquette(ostream& sortie) const {
    sortie << nom << " : " << volume << " ml, pH " << pH;
    return sortie;}
```

I have the error :

> error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘(’ token

At line 27 :

```
ostream& Flacon::etiquette(ostream& sortie) const {
```

Thank you for your help

I would also like to know why this.name displays an error when this->name does not display one

Comment: You are missing `}` after `return *this;` and before `ostream& Flacon::etiquette...` (i.e. the closing brace for `operator+` function)

Comment: Unrelated, but check out [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) `operator+` is not expected to modify any object and it will confuse anyone who uses `Flacon` class.

Comment: Do you mean `this->nom` in the last question?

Comment: I put + in internal overload to avoid creating another useless variable in memory that will be the result of this addition, isn't that good?

Comment: Yes, i wanted to mean this->nom

Comment: @HitanElo You've writen an version of `operator+` that does not behave in the same way as a normal `operator+`, so no that's not good. In fact your `operator+` is just like `operator+=` so you should rename it.

Comment: @HitanElo Imagine I use this class. I have two objects: `Flacon a;` and `Flacon b;`. Now I write this line: `Flacon c = a + b;`. Quite reasonable, isn't it? But now both `a` and `c` contain summed value and I don't have the value from `a` anymore...

Comment: `this->nom` works because `this` is a pointer, `this.nom` does not work because, well, `this` is a pointer.

Comment: I understand, you(re right, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The reason to why `this.nom` causes an error is because `this` is a pointer. I believe that you should be able to use `(*this).nom` instead if you are used to Java but that might be bad practise. I would personally suggest that you use `this->nom`.

**See:**

> a.b is only used if b is a member of the object (or reference[1] to an
>   object) a.  So for a.b, a will always be an actual object (or a
>   reference to an object) of a class.

**And:**

> a →b is essentially a shorthand notation for (*a).b, ie, if a is a
>   pointer to an object, then a→b is accessing the property b of the
>   object that points to.

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-arrow-operator-in-Cplusplus

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @HitanElo if the answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted so it can help other users aswell!